# Lync Server 2010 Installation problem on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: lync

On Deploy -> Step 1: Install Local Configuration Store I get this error:

**Automatic collection of configuration data failed.**

All pre-requisites are met.

Comment: We're going to need a lot more information please - also given this is a new and paid-for product have you opened a case with MS already?

Comment: All Licensed software, just thought I missed something obvious - so havn't phoned MS yet. Will do thanks.

Comment: Got these links from Microsoft on how to install Lync, use only one of these tutorials: http://www.ocspedia.com/fe/Install_Microsoft_Lync_Server_2010.aspx?ArticleID=103

http://imaucblog.com/archive/2010/09/15/step-by-step-microsoft-lync-2010-consolidated-standard-server-install-guide/

Answer (score 1):

You need to build a topology first and deploy it to the central configuration store.  This generally happens in the install prerequisites steps, I think.  If you haven't gotten to the point where you've fiddled in topology builder, I'm pretty sure something's amiss.

If you did set up a topology and published it to AD, did you follow the "Extra steps required" that pop up in a notepad when you click "To-do list?"  One of those might have been to setup a dns record required for the system to find sql, just a thought.